# Checkbox column in ejgrid syncfusion

Tags: syncfusion

I am Using **SyncFusion ejGrid** i.e. in my project.

I want to show **Checkbox** in first column to **select/unselect multiple rows**.
One **checkbox** in the column header to **select/unselect all**.

Comment: Hi, How did you got selected rows to sent to server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add checkbox to Grid Column content we can use “templateId” property of columns and to add checkbox to Column header we can use “headerTemplateId” property. Then in checkbox click event we can select row by using “selectRows” method of Grid.

```
 <script type="text/x-jsrender" id="check">
    <input type="checkbox" class="rowCheckbox" id="chk" />
</script>
<script type="text/x-jsrender" id="head">
    <input type="checkbox" id="headchk" />
</script>

$("#Grid").ejGrid({
        ...
        columns: [
                     { headerTemplateId: "#head", columnTemplate: true, templateId: "#check" },   
        ...
        });
    $("#headchk").change(function () {
            $("#Grid .rowCheckbox").on("change", checkChange);
            gridObj = $("#Grid").data("ejGrid");
            if ($("#headchk").is(':checked')) {// TO Select all rows in Grid Content
            …
                gridObj.selectRows(0, gridObj.model.pageSettings.pageSize);
            }
            else {       // To remove selection for all rows
            …
                gridObj.cleanUpSelection();
            }
        });
    function checkChange(e) {
            …
            //For MultiSelection using Checkbox
            gridObj._multiSelectCtrlRequest = true;
    }
```

I have created a sample based on your requirement and the same can be downloaded from below link.
Sample: http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/125963/grid898060682.zip

Comment: Your solution worked for me.
I really appreciate your response.
Thank you so much.

Comment: How can we get selected Rows to send to server

Comment: ineffable - Oon checkbox click event we can select row by using “selectRows” method of Grid. Loop through in Jquery and send it to server in Json.